# Which is easier on the eyes: dark-on-light or light-on-dark?

Tags: typography, text, color-theory

While working on my latest website, I started actually wondering if what I learned in grade school was true. I've been taught that programs like Word default to use a white background with black text because it's easier on the eyes than the old phosphorous displays which were always light-on-dark. However, I find more and more that it hurts much less for me to read light text on a dark background; my lenses feel like they're straining less, and irises can relax more due to the lower overall light level.

So **is it true that dark-on-light is easier to read?** Have we just been told this to make us believe that these programs are advanced or something like that? Was the change to dark-on-light made more to simulate ink-on-paper moreso than for visual comfort?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/14/5489

Comment: Slightly, though mine brings up other issues as well

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors such as the level of ambient light.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

from http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2008/10/13/why-light-text-on-dark-background-is-a-bad-idea/:

> The science of readability is by no means new, and some of the best research comes from advertising works in the early 80s. This information is still relevant today.
>
> First up is this quote from a paper titled “Improving the legibility of visual display units through contrast reversal”. In present time we think of contrast reversal meaning black-on-white, but remember this paper is from 1980 when VDUs (monitors) where green-on-black. This paper formed part of the research that drove the push for this to change to the screen formats we use today.
>
> > However, most studies have shown that dark characters on a light
> >     background are superior to light characters on a dark background (when
> >     the refresh rate is fairly high). For example, Bauer and Cavonius
> >     (1980) found that participants were 26% more accurate in reading text
> >     when they read it with dark characters on a light background.
> >
> > Reference: Bauer, D., & Cavonius, C., R. (1980). Improving the
> >     legibility of visual display units through contrast reversal. In E.
> >     Grandjean, E. Vigliani (Eds.), Ergonomic Aspects of Visual Display
> >     Terminals (pp. 137-142). London: Taylor & Francis
>
> Ok, 26% improvement – but why?
>
> > People with astigmatism (aproximately 50% of the population) find it
> >     harder to read white text on black than black text on white. Part of
> >     this has to do with light levels: with a bright display (white
> >     background) the iris closes a bit more, decreasing the effect of the
> >     "deformed" lens; with a dark display (black background) the iris opens
> >     to receive more light and the deformation of the lens creates a much
> >     fuzzier focus at the eye.
> >
> > Jason Harrison – Post Doctoral Fellow, Imager Lab Manager – Sensory
> >     Perception and Interaction Research Group, University of British
> >     Columbia
>
> The "fuzzing” effect that Jason refers to is known as halation.
>
> It might feel strange pushing your primary design goals based on the vision impaired, but when 50% of the population of have this “impairment” it’s actually closer to being the norm than an impairment.
>
> The web is rife with research on the topic, but I think these two quotes provide a succinct justification for why light text on a dark background is a bad idea.

Comment: +1 Great answer! It also explains why in my personal experience I find pure white on black harder to read than mid-light greys but no equivalent problem with black on white. I'd wondered about that for a long time.

Comment: This answer is a verbatim copy of this blog post, so unless you're Tatham a link to the source would be welcome :) http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2008/10/13/why-light-text-on-dark-background-is-a-bad-idea/

Comment: This quote seems odd; 50% of the population having an impairment does *not* make it the norm. It makes it half. Also how is the 50% number approximated; is it rounded up or down? How many people have astigmatisms today vs then? How many of those people (and people in general) spend a significant time each day staring at a screen now compared to then? (I think to that last one at least we can say "significantly more").

Comment: In europe and asia the numbers vary from 30% to 60% of the population. The older the popoulation the higher the number. Astigmatism is also on rise, possibly because of urbanisation. So yes this is definitively a issue you should heed. Imagine selling 30% less product because of your choice of background?

Answer (score 4):

I do hours and hours of editing and translating in front of a computer all day, and my experience is that for such text-heavy work, light text on a dark background (for me, either white or a very light green on a black background) leaves me less fatigued, noticing far less strain on the eyes. Doing such intensive, long editing and translating with dark text on a white background is like staring into a fluorescent light bulb all day. Of course, if you're just browsing around the Internet for briefer periods, it's enjoyable to see all the various design choices web besigners have made, and some of them are worthy of being called works of art, but for plain old drudgery, simple, retro light-on-dark seems superior to me.

Comment: Hi Gary, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Yes, my experience is similar. It could be that dark-on-light is slightly more *readable* especially for those with astigmatism (see other answer), however light-on-dark is less *fatiguing*. As a coder, I always prefer light-on-dark colour schemes, especially when I might be staring at it for hours. Would be interesting to see some research on this, though.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
If you need to read long texts, use a dark font on a light gray (better than plain white) background.

For all other purposes, use a dark background instead

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE! Where does this knowledge come from? Book, study, ...