# Choosing a good highlight color for dark background

Tags: color-theory, contrast

I'm working on a dark design which is composed on a list with alternated row colors ( #252425 and #121314 ) and I use different colors for the text on it ( #85bb23, #6F6A6F, #FFFFFF, #C50005, #2AAADB ).

[image]

Every time I choose a color to highlight a line (on click), I realize that its combination with one of the colors above looks ugly (or the text become unreadable because of low contrast)

Is there a technique (or a tool) to choose this color efficiently?

Comment: The dark red definitely gives insufficient contrast. Try some colors that work, e.g. http://websafecolors.info/ or http://flatuicolors.com/

Comment: Also, try different displays, some happen to have less contrast than others. It's sometimes surprising to see how awful your design looks on a low contrast display.

Comment: [This question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45673/any-problems-with-light-text-on-dark-background) might help! Do you have a sample with your selected state, or is the grey one selected?

Answer (score 4):

The highlighting of your row could be a **solid color** instead. If the color uses the whole horizontal space, and your text remains white, you only need to worry about the color looking ok with the rest of the text.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are different colour palette creators, some that help you create your own and some that give you user generated palettes as well, using them you can find other combinations that might work. The main tools I like are *Adobe Kuler*, recently renamed as *[Adobe Color CC](https://color.adobe.com/)* and *Colourlovers*

Comment: This answer doesn't even mention highlighting - the entire purpose of the question